# php DOMDocument removeChild throws exception of not found

Tags: php, xml, dom, domdocument

remove is failing with not found exception.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught DOMException: Not Found Error
```

```
$document = new \DOMDocument();
$raw = '
some text
<a href="sad" sometag="true">linkkkk</a>
more text
';
$document->loadHTML($raw);

$links = $document->getElementsByTagName('a');
$a = $links->item(0);

$document->removeChild($a);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove it from the parentNode from `$a`

```
$document = new \DOMDocument();
$raw = '
some text
<a href="sad" sometag="true">linkkkk</a>
more text
';
$document->loadHTML($raw);

$links = $document->getElementsByTagName('a');
$a = $links->item(0);
$a->parentNode->removeChild($a);
```

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByTagName()` returns a list of any descendant element node `a`. So `$links` is not the parent node.

With PHP > 8.0 you can use the method `DOMNode::remove()`:

```php
$links = $document->getElementsByTagName('a');
$a = $links->item(0);
$a->remove();
```

Or use the `parentNode` property:

```php
$links = $document->getElementsByTagName('a');
$a = $links->item(0);
$a->parentNode->removeChild($a);
```